# Count occurrences of "Monday" in a different sheet from a given date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In one sheet I have a set of dates (in column A):

**Sheet 1:**

```
05/03/2021
05/03/2021
05/04/2021
05/05/2021
...
05/28/2021
```

In another sheet, I have 2 named cells: from_date and to_date (for a report range)

**Sheet 2:**

```
from_date = 05/03/2021
to_date = 05/28/2021
```

In Sheet 2, I want to return the number of occurrences of Mondays in column A from Sheet 1.

I currently have:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(Sheet1!A:A)=2))
```

which is returning the number of Mondays in all of column A. I could change the range inside WEEKDAY(), but that defeats the purpose of being able to change the report range at the top and have the entire sheet update dynamically. How can I set the cell up so that when I update the value of the report range in Sheet 2, it will calculate the occurrences of Monday in Sheet 1?

Comment: Excel or Google Spreadsheets? Google Spreadsheets are off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of Excel:

```
=COUNT(FILTER(Sheet1!$A:$A,(Sheet1!$A:$A>=from_date)*(Sheet1!$A:$A<=to_date)*(WEEKDAY(Sheet1!$A:$A)=2)))
```

The above formula will work in Excel Office 365

Comment: Is there a way to do it using COUNTIFS? I've tried =COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A, ">="&from_date, Sheet1!A:A, "<="&to_date, Sheet1!A:A, 2)

Comment: @Andrew I doubt it.  In `COUNTIFS`, the criteria ranges have to be **ranges**, not arrays, so not sure how you would include the `WEEKDAY` parameter.